# Tengo un error al momento de hacer un commit en Vuex

Tags: vue.js, typescript, vuex

Tienda:
/strore/index.ts

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import auth from './modules/auth';
import VuexPersist from 'vuex-persist';
Vue.use(Vuex);

const vuexPersist = new VuexPersist({
    key: 'my-app',
    storage: window.localStorage
});

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {},
    mutations: {},
    actions: {},
    modules: {
        auth
    },
    plugins: [vuexPersist.plugin]
});
```

Este es el modulo de auth: /stroe/modules/auth.ts

```
export default {
    state: {
        session: false,
        name: '',
        email: '',
        lastname: '',
        auth: {
            access_token: '',
            token_type: '',
            expires_at: ''
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        setUser(state, data) {
            // state = data;
            state.session = true;
        }
    },
    actions: {
        updateUser(context, data) {
            context.commit('setUser', data);
        }
    }
};
```

Hora cuando hago un commit me sale el siguiente error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Descubrí que cuando no modifico el **state** sigue funcionando la aplicación normalmente.

También descubrí que el problema no lo genera **VuexPersist** dado que lo elimine para descartarlo y el problema persistió.

Esta es la forma en la que utilizo las tiendas.

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import axios from '@/clients/axios.ts';
import { mapMutations } from 'vuex';
export default Vue.extend({
     methods: {

        ...mapMutations(['setUser']),
        async register() {

            try {
                const register = await axios.post('auth/register', this.user);
                this.setUser({ ...this.user, auth: { ...register.data } });
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Eso parecemas un error de un componente que del store.. que hay en ese componente que tira error?

Comment: Pues el componente funciona bien, solo empezó a fallar cuando agregue el store. La lógica que puse es prácticamente todo el componente. Solo le falta la data que guarda los datos de usuario.

Comment: Estas seguro que solo agregaste codigo en el store? ese parece más un error del vue-router, que está haciendo redirecciones en bucle a la misma vista, en tu guard que controla este store probablemente este el problema.

Comment: Si solo era el store. Creo que tiene algo que ver con typescript por que pase todo a javascript normal y funciono optimamente. Aun no se mucho sobre typescript.

Comment: ¿Puedes crear una demo online y compartir el link?